# How to avoid new for angular components written im Emca 6?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I'm declaring a very simple angular component like so:

```
import htmlTemplate from './searchInput.html'

export default class SearchInput {

    constructor() {
        this.template = htmlTemplate;
    }

}
```

And then I use it like this:

```
import SearchInput from './components/searchInput/searchInput';

angular.module('prj', [])
    .component('searchInput', new SearchInput());
```

That works fine.

But all examples with angular 1.x and ECMA 6 I found so far do not call `new` on the `SearchInput` class. If I ommit the `new` the template is not loaded.
If I want to be able to change my code to (no new),

```
angular.module('prj', [])
    .component('searchInput', SearchInput());
```

what do I have to change?

Comment: Tried Reflect.construct('SearchInput', '') ?

Comment: Where should i put that and what is it supposed to do?

Comment: .component('searchInput', Reflect.construct('SearchInput', '')); give that a try

Comment: `.component` expects an object. I have no idea why you want to declare a "class" in the first place.

Comment: Because this is done here (https://github.com/timroes/angular-es6-sample/blob/master/src/scripts/app.js) and in a lot of other examples. I'm wondering why this never works for me.

Comment: It is done there for `controller` and `service`, because they expect a constructor function, As well as in a lot of other examples. `component` expects an object, not a constructor.

Comment: Ok, got it. Thanks! Feal free to add this as answer to get the credits.

Comment: Then stamp as accepted answer, and vote up

Answer (score 0):

Try `.component('searchInput', new SearchInput());` not as function call. Since that way will expect from the `contructor()` a `return value`

```
class SearchInput()
{
    constructor()
    {
        this.template = ... // whatever value you see fit
    }
    controller()
    {
        ... // implements your logic
    }
}
```

The new is just the controller method

---

See this example I used for tests:

JAVASCRIPT

```
(() =>
{
    'use strict';
    class BackgroundDetail
    {
        constructor()
        {
            this.template = `<fieldset>
                                <label>{{$ctrl.name}}</label>
                                <span>
                                    Master:
                                    <em>
                                        {{$ctrl.master}}
                                    </em>
                                </span>
                                <hr/>
                                <input ng-model="$ctrl.master">
                                <pre>{{$ctrl|json}}</pre>
                            </fieldset>`;
        }
        controller()
        {
            var self = this;
            self.master = 'Jesus';
            self.name = 'Salathiel Genèse';
        }
    }



    angular.module('app', [])
    .component('backgroundDetail', new BackgroundDetail());
})();
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" ng-app="app" ng-cloak ng-strict-di>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{app.title}}</title>
        <!-- AngularJs requirements  -->
        <script src="web/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="web/libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <!-- app requirements -->
        <script src="web/js/javascript.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <background-detail></background-detail>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Same result, the template is not loaded.

Comment: I've not yet read about angular compoenent but the example [here shown](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component) takes as second parameter an `Object` with relevant attributes `{templateUrl, controller}` but I think `{template, controller}` should work the same. Thus let me edit my post

Comment: Stil same result. As soon I ommit the `new`  (and the `()` ) nothing is shown.

Comment: :) I hope you didn't copy my `contructor` instead of `constructor` : pay attention to the `s`. I've just discover the flaw during tracing

Comment: If it still not work, then check that `import` works as expected. I'm using simple javascript, not `TypeScript` or like